# Apache Virtual Host does not work

Tags: apache, virtualhost, localhost, xampp, windows-7

I've problems setting up a virtual host on windows7, so that I can develop multiple pages on my localhost.
To set up the virtual Host, I've edited 3 Files:

- **httpd-vhosts.conf** in apache\conf\extra
- **httpd.conf** in apache\conf
- **hosts** in system32\drivers\etc

This is what I've done in order to make the page run on Port 81:

added this block in **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\mypage
    ServerName mypage
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\mypage">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

made apache Listen on Port 81 in **httpd.conf**

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
```

added this line in **hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    mypage
```

But as soon as I try to access mypage via localhost:81, I get redirected to localhost/xampp.

Comment: In `httpd.conf` is it properly loading `httpd-vhosts.conf`? Or is that line commented out?

Comment: Why are you making Apache2 listen on port 81? You don't have to use a different port for a virtual host.

Comment: The Line is not commented out. I used a different port because I did it exactly the same way on an other pc and it worked

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite active? If so, enable RewriteLog and see what it's doing. Otherwise, monitor the HTTP traffic and check Apache's main logs. See how you're being redirected to the different hostname.

Answer (score 1):

You **must**

- Read [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)
- Understand Apache docs
- Select better-suited module for virtual-hosts for your needs (from at least two)
- Enable selected module in LoadModule
- Restart Apache after editing configs